# Add fixed item in FirebaseRecyclerOptions

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` object where I fill it doing this :

```
final FirebaseRecyclerOptions< CardPOJO > options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder< CardPOJO >()
                        .setQuery(products_ref, CardPOJO.class)
                        .build();
```

I'd like to add a fixed item as a last item, is there any way to do that?
Following I have the:

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter< CardPOJO, CardHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            public CardHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                //inflate the single recycler view layout(item)
                ...
```

I'd like to do something like

```
options.add(new CardPOJO("BLABLA","BLABLA"));
```

Because no matter what I have to add an object of a `CardPOJO` class, don't I?

Explanation with an image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, instead of passing a `DatabaseReference` object inside the `setQuery()` method, pass a `Query` object.

Use that query to limit to a fiexed number of items:

```
Query query = products_ref.orderByChild("yourChild")
    .equalsTo("desiredChild")
    .limitToLast(1);
```

or more simply:

```
Query query = products_ref.limitToLast(1);
```

Then in your adapter use `getItem(position)` and change the value of that item with de desired one.

Another approach would be to attach a listener on that particular node, get the last item and change it with what ever you want.

Comment: But I want it to be always the last, I do not have a fixed num of cards

Comment: What is yourChild and desiredChild? I guess your Child is "products" because I had this : `products_ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products");`

Comment: But I have to add it on my firebase database? I didn't want to do that...

Comment: I added `yourChild` and `desiredChild` because usually we query after a property but remove those method calls. See my updated answer.

Comment: If I do this, all the items that I have is my last on the database

Comment: So isn't it what you are looking for? Have you tried to use `getItem(position)` and pass the `position` being the item?

Comment: Well.. maybe I missexplained... what I'd like is to have the last item something like ADD, for example I have a list of numbers 1,2,3,4,5 and the last I want to be + and when user click on it then do my job. You got me now?

Comment: No, I did not. Can please be more specific or give me a concrete example?

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot understand.

Comment: it's simple, just like this image https://fthmb.tqn.com/0gFKIPVn0-Rv50Z_WsyfP3Zd_vo=/768x0/filters:no_upscale()/steptwo-59c9469803f4020010d50ae9.png its for add a new value

Comment: Use `push()` method, and the item that you are adding it will always be the last. It this what you want?

Comment: where do I have to add push method?

Comment: You can use it directly on your referece. yourRef.push().setValue(yourObject);

Comment: I told to use this when when addind data in order to get the last item.

Comment: I cannot code for you, I just provided you some guidelines on how to achieve this but in the same time, it's hard for me to understand what you actually want to achieve. I'm sorry, I tried to help.